# link function inside angularjs directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tNWwx/)

Neither the directive is rendering, nor the link function of that directive being called.

Code:
JS

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("directives", []);

    app.directive("mySample", function() {
        return {
            restric: "E",
            replace: true,
            template: "<div>sample directive</div>",
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                console.log(elem);
            }
        };
    });
}());
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="directives">
      <my-sample></my-sample>
</body>
```

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: are there any errors in your console to accompany this non-working behavior?

Comment: No. I wish there is any error to narrow down my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive has a `restric` attribute, where it should be `restrict` (missing final 't').

Comment: Thanks Gamb. Not sure why I couldn't see that. Maybe time of the day :)

Comment: @Nexus23 It happens, I know your pain ;).